как отфильтровать товары по категориям Django
есть две модели: Категории и Подкатегории
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, related_name='child',  null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('Категория', max_length=150, default='name')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Картинка', upload_to='img', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('url', 'parent',)
    verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Подкатегория', max_length=150, default=True)
   url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)
   image = models.ImageField('Картинка', upload_to='img', null=True, blank=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Подкатегория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Подкатегории'

помогите написать правильную view для фильтрации именно по подкатегориям, на данный момент выводятся просто все подкатегории
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
   model = Category
   queryset = Category.objects.all()
   template_name = 'catalog/category_list.html'
   context_object_name = 'category_list'


class SubCategoriesListView(Category, ListView):
   model = SubCategory
   queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
   template_name = 'catalog/subcategory_list.html'
   context_object_name = 'subcategory_list'


urls.py 
   path('', views.CategoriesListView.as_view(), name='category_view'),
   path('<category_slug>/', views.SubCategoriesListView.as_view(), name='subcategory_view'),

пробовал через MPTT - не получилось, решил через listview, потому что далее необходим класс Detailview

Например можете добавить функцию в класс Category:
def get_subcategorie(self)         return self.subcategory_set.all()
